# Mysterious happenings in Windows Batch, Not escaping correctly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

This is part of my windows batch script:

```
@echo cd /data/backup/> working\grab__test

@echo line1 'length($0)^>7{$0^=substr^($0,1 >> working\grab__test
```

This is not the real world code, just the isolated parts to show the problem.

They should be writing lines to file grab__test. What gets written to grab__test is:

```
line1 'length($0
```

What is going on?? If I don't escape the > and = I get an even wierder error:

```
1 was unexpected at this time.
```

What?? Why *THAT* 1 at the end of the line in particular?? There are other numerical digits, why not 7? Why does the second line that has the > escaped keep writing to the file? 
Arg!

Comment: RIght Parentheses are special characters.  They need to be escaped if you want to echo them to a file.

Comment: Solved! The problem, not my curiousity and confusion.. Thanks! Why are only right parentheses special characters? (I'm usually visiting http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php to refresh memory, but no mention of that on this page)

Comment: Because batch is kinda wonky when it comes to nesting things.

Comment: It's actually just a mite more complex - or simpler, depending on your view. The fact is that the code you've posted works perfectly. You've over-cropped your code. You actually have this code within a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines) like an `if` or a `do`. Under these circumstances, batch sees an un-escaped `)` as closing the `(` that opens the block. If it's a literal, it needs to be escaped. The mighty-weird thing is that `(` isn't similarly interpreted - although if I ever get time, I might try a literal `if/else` being echoed within a block & see whether that changes things

Comment: Yeah, @magoo is 100% correct, all you needed to know in just a comment block.

Comment: The 1 is interpreted as input/output to StdOut. The number 2 representing standard error. 7 also has some meaning as well. You added a space so you can output the literal charachter 1 instead of it "disappearing" When you fix the errors this will be fixed as well. This is a good example of how a bug can cause other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The command line

```
@echo line1 'length($0)^>7{$0^=substr^($0,1 >> working\grab__test
```

works as expected outside of a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)`. It is not necessary to escape the equal sign `=` and opening parenthesis `(` in this command line. It is only necessary to escape right angle bracket `>` as being otherwise interpreted as redirection operator.

But inside a command block it is not working as expect because Windows command interpreter interprets not escaped closing parenthesis `)` as end of command block started somewhere above with `(`. So within a command block each `)` in an argument string not enclosed in double quotes like here must be escaped with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character.

Here is a code demonstrating this difference.

```
@echo off
set "OutputFile=%TEMP%\Test.tmp"
echo Line 1: 'length($0)^>7{$0=substr($0,1 >"%OutputFile%"
>>"%OutputFile%" echo Line 2: 'length($0)^>7{$0=substr($0,1
(
>>"%OutputFile%" echo Line 3: 'length($0^)^>7{$0=substr($0,1
)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do echo "%%I"
del "%OutputFile%"
set "OutputFile="
```

The output is:

```
"Line 1: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1 "
"Line 2: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1"
"Line 3: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1"
```

The code uses a **FOR** loop to output each line separately with command **ECHO** enclosed in double quotes instead of `type "%OutputFile%"` to show the difference between line 1 and line 2.

There is a space between `1` at end of string to write into the file and the redirection operator `>` on the command line writing line 1 into the file. This space is necessary as otherwise the character `1` would not be written into the file. But this space character belongs to the string which **ECHO** outputs and results therefore in a trailing space in the file.

The solution to avoid this trailing space is specifying the redirection left to the **ECHO** command as done on the command lines writing line 2 and 3 into the file.

Let us debug this batch file by modifying the first line to `@echo on` and run the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on it. (Environment variable `TEMP` is defined for this example output with `C:\Windows\Temp`.)

```
set "OutputFile=C:\Windows\Temp\Test.tmp"

echo Line 1: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1  1>"C:\Windows\Temp\Test.tmp"

echo Line 2: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1 1>>"C:\Windows\Temp\Test.tmp"

(echo Line 3: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1 1>>"C:\Windows\Temp\Test.tmp"
 )

for /F "usebackq delims=" %I in ("C:\Windows\Temp\Test.tmp") do echo "%I"

echo "Line 1: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1 "
"Line 1: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1 "

echo "Line 2: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1"
"Line 2: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1"

echo "Line 3: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1"
"Line 3: 'length($0)>7{$0=substr($0,1"

del "C:\Windows\Temp\Test.tmp"

set "OutputFile="
```

Some command lines really executed after preprocessing each command line or entire command block before execution look different than written in batch file.

On the command line outputting first line into the file `>` is modified to  `1>`, i.e. a space and `1` is inserted. So there are now two spaces between `$0,1` to write into the file and `1>` which redirects **STDOUT** to the specified file. That is the reason why the first space after `$0,1` is also written into the file.

On the command lines output second and third line the redirection specified left to command **ECHO** is now on right side with  `1>>` instead of just `>>` and with just one space between `$0,1` and `1>>`. For that reason those two lines are written into the file without a trailing space.

Also interesting to see is how the command block is reformatted by Windows command interpreter.

Whenever a batch file is not running as expected it is highly recommended to modify `@echo off` to `@echo on` or remove that line or comment it out with command **REM** (or invalid label `::`) and run the batch file from within a command prompt window to see what is really executed by Windows command interpreter after preprocessing each command line and command block.